# How to find current drain out of a connected USB device?

Tags: power-supply, power, current, usb

I am in the process of creating a tester for production for a custom USB programming device made by my company. In this tester, I am connecting the custom USB device to our computer, and I am not sure if there may be some current drain on the device, in which I will have to supply with an additional power supply. How do I find this out?

Comment: Buy a "USB doctor" stick to measure the current.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy one of these:

[image]

Image found [here](https://www.hellasdigital.gr/electronics/sensors/current-sensors/um24c-usb-2.0-color-lcd-display-tester-voltage-current-meter-voltmeter-amperimetro-battery-charge-measure-cable-resistance-with-bluetooth/)

But bare in mind they are not always accurate (if you buy them from [aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000037898130.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.1c4033f63a6vN3&algo_pvid=b9188a73-a118-470e-855a-1e7975c0af0e&algo_expid=b9188a73-a118-470e-855a-1e7975c0af0e-0&btsid=0b0a557016153086070177029ecd5f&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_) like i did, you will end up with a +- 20mA current error.

Another device you can buy (for sure results) is a micro-current measurement device https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/

[image]

which you can also [build by yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g7b5YZENvjY).

And you can also (if you have an accurate Amp-meter) cut your usb Vcc wire and hook the amp-meter in series, you will see how much mAmps it draws.